# Async/Await function not returning any values

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```js
foo();

function foo(){
    let fooPromise = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        var dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
        dbConn.connect().then(function () {
            var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
            request.query(`SELECT TOP 1 someDate FROM Stable `).then(function (recordSet) {
                
                var lastSaledate = recordSet.recordset[0].someDate;
                return resolve(lastSaledate);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                return reject(err);
            });
        });
    });
  
    let fooPromisereturn = await fooPromise;

    console.log(fooPromisereturn);
    return fooPromisereturn // I want this value to be return whlile calling foo()
}
```

Comment: First of all. When you assign async over a function its implied that it will return a promise so using new Promise over it doesn't make any sense. also you need to await for the dbconnection

Comment: You can only `await fooPromise` inside `foo` if you make `foo` `async`. When `foo` is `async` it'll need to be `await`ed as well. This is because you cannot return a value which will be available *sometime later* **right now**. You *have* to `await` values which will only be available *sometime later*.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!